# Shopify - Accessing to the products in my collection list

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-template

what I'm trying to do is display a specific products through my "Newest Products". And I'm trying to display the products based on whats included in the product title.

The problem is it's not displaying all of the products that contains i provided in the code.

For example:

```
{% assign newestProducts = collections['newest-products'].products %}

<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    {% for product in newestProducts %}
      {% if product.title contains 'Evandros' %}
        {% if product.featured_image %}
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.title }}">
            <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
            <a href="{{ product.url }}">View Product</a>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>


<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: '10',
    spaceBetween: 20,
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
  });
</script>
```

I used {% if product.title contains 'Evandros' %} in this example and there are total of 3 products but its only displaying 2 of them.

Another example is i have a "x" product that has "y" contains in the product title but its not even showing any of those product.

I also tried to count how many products were included in collection by code

```
{% assign collectionHandle = 'newest-products' %}
{% assign productCount = 0 %}

{% for collection in collections %}
  {% if collection.handle == collectionHandle %}
    {% assign productCount = collection.products_count %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

The total number of products: {{ productCount }
```

The count was 638 but thats not correct because when I check it through Shopify Admin panel there are 878 products were assigned right now.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here is probably due to pagination limit to 50 products per page (the missing 3rd product would be on another page).

You might want to prefilter the array to get only products you want to display, using a where filter for example. But you'll need something more specific than a contains conditions as the "where" filter doesn't support a "contains" condition (only equals or boolean).

For example:

```
{% assign newestProducts = collections['newest-products'].products | where:'vendor','Evandros' %}
```

More infos about the where filter:
https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/where/